# Pymongo Asyncmongo $maxDistance not working

Tags: mongodb, tornado, pymongo, asyncmongo

I'm trying to query `MongoDB geo` using `$maxDistance`. But its not working in both `PyMongo` and `AsyncMongo`

**AsyncMongo**

```
self.application.asyncdb.places.find({"loc":{"$near":[longitude, latitude], "$maxDistance":1000}}, limit=20, callback=self.showNearByPlaces)
```

**PyMongo**

```
placeColl = self.application.db.places
cursorObj = placeColl.find({"loc": {"$near":(longitude, latitude)},"$maxDistance":1000})
```

Comment: Can you explain the symptom? What is not working? The PyMongo example does not appear to be using $maxDistance.

Comment: thats what i want to achieve in my pymongo. i want to implement **$maxDistance**. is there any other way to get it.

Comment: I'm still not clear what is not working. Can you clarify what you have tried and the result? Have you tried getting a query working in the mongo shell?

Comment: I'm trying to get places which are all **near**, but i want to get only places near to **2 or 3 meters** from my current latitude and longitude

Comment: Your query is using legacy coordinates, and is therefore in radians. If you want to use meters, use GeoJSON - see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example using PyMongo 2.6.3 and MongoDB 2.4.8:

```
>>> from pymongo import MongoClient
>>> from bson import SON
>>> c = MongoClient()
>>> collection = c.db.collection
>>> collection.drop()
>>> collection.create_index([('loc', '2d')])
u'loc_2d'
>>> collection.insert({'loc': [1, 1]})
ObjectId('52d19a5eca1ce961b94f23f4')
>>> collection.insert({'loc': [3, 3]})
ObjectId('52d19a69ca1ce961b94f23f5')
>>> list(collection.find({'loc': SON([('$near', [0, 0]), ('$maxDistance', 2)])}))
[{u'loc': [1, 1], u'_id': ObjectId('52d19a5eca1ce961b94f23f4')}]
```

You can see that the point within 2 units of [0, 0] is included in the results, and the farther point is excluded.

Unlike most MongoDB queries, `$near` queries require the keys to be in a particular order. `$near` must come before `$maxDistance`, not after. Since regular Python dicts don't preserve the order of the keys, I used a `bson.SON`, which is installed as part of the PyMongo package. `SON` is like a dictionary but preserves order.